# Converting a code from Python to Ruby

Tags: python, ruby

I have this code in Python:

```
parameters = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 }
urllib.urlencode(dict(itertools.chain(parameters.iteritems(), [('aaa', 'bbb')])))
```

What's the equivalent code in Ruby? What I know is that I have to use `CGI::escape` instead of `urllib.urlencode`. `parameters.iteritems()` - probably `parameters.map`. What's the rest?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code translation service. Show us what you have tried, and then ask *specific* questions about *specific* problems you are having. And for the benefit of those who don't speak Python, it would help if you would tell us what the code that you want us to write for you even does.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, you're fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Python code outputs:

```
a=1&b=2&aaa=bbb
```

In Ruby we might do this as:

```
require 'cgi'

parameters = {a: 1, b: 2}

encoded = parameters.merge(Hash[*['aaa', 'bbb']])
    .map { |key, value| "#{CGI.escape key.to_s}=#{CGI.escape value.to_s}" }
    .join('&')

p encoded
```

Which outputs the same:

```
a=1&b=2&aaa=bbb
```

It's longer than the Python code, but IMHO also slightly more readable ... You could make it shorter if you wanted to by making a version `CGI::escape` that accepts a Hash, and not just strings.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

```
parameters.merge({ 'aaa' => 'bbb' }).map{ |k, v| "#{CGI.escape(k)}=#{CGI.escape(v)}" }.join("&")
```